# Full Calendar Event with Travel Time first 30 Min and last 30 Min

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

Please help me in creating an Create event with below scenario .

Creating an event for a 3 hour block of time. The first and last 30 minutes of an event is considered travel time. Example: If customer appointment is at 2 pm, block 1:30 – 4:30 pm on the calendar.

How do i achieve this , is their a way i can work with multiple background color , first and last 30 min with different color . and event with different color .

Kindly suggest an approach to make this work .

Thanks,
Jagdish

Comment: If you want to use different colours for each part you'd have to declare it as 3 separate events. AFAIK that's the only way to do that reliably.

Comment: Also, are you using fullcalendar 2, or fullcalendar 3? Don't tag both, tag the one you're actually using. Tag spam is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks Adyson, creating an 3 event would be my final approach . i would like to check is their any other way via Css having 2 color with background as first 30 and last 30 Min with green color and in between with different color .

Comment: Not really AFAIK because the event is all one HTML cell, and there's no way to know accurately what % of the cell covers a specific time period.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply . I will go by creating 3 event or by adding a background Image via css className  with fixed travel time .